# Sitecore - Show ProgressBox

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am using the Smart copy tool available for download which allows me to create a new version of an item and copy its contents.

We downloaded the code in order to make a few changes. While the code works in all environemnts, on deployment to production, the Add Version and Copy Data option throws the following exception, but successfully completes the operation.
The exception it throws is:

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at 
System.Web. HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& 
completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: job
Source: Sitecore.Client
at 
Sitecore.Shell.Applications. Dialogs.Progress.ProgressPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

It thows this exception when trying to show the Progress box.

This is the line that fails:

```
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.ProgressBoxes.ProgressBox.Execute("Add 
Version and Copy", "Smart Tools", new ProgressBoxMethod(ExecuteOperation), 
itemFromQueryString);
```

Note that deployments to all other PAAS environments have worked successfully.

What could be the reason and the fix for this please?

Comment: Can you post the full error stack you are getting?

Comment: Updated with full stack

Comment: Could it be that one of the dlls are missing?

Comment: We've checked and they all seem to be in there.

Comment: You may need to check DLL versions? Based on the stack trace, it looks like ExecuteOperation is not a valid operation, but since it works in other environments, might just be you have the DLL but it's an old version or something?